# How to add a person in a scene with image as planes?

Tags: image

I made this scene and Im not good at making a 3d character so I tried to add a person into a scene with an image texture. The problem now is that I dont know how to make it look like that its a real person and not an image?
[image]

(I rendert this at a low sample rate so the fog on the left looks weird because of denoising, just ignore)

Comment: besides the fact that the image is jut too bright

Comment: what do you mean exactly with lower value, mix shader with transparent? And how do you blur sth in the shading editor?

Comment: You don't tell about your setup, do you have lights? Is you image plugged into a Diffuse? In the latter case, put a Color > RGB Curve between the Image Texture and the Diffuse and lower down the first curve. Also you could create a shadow

Comment: my setup looks like this https://imgur.com/a/YgRzAO4 I have a light shining on the back of the picture and one in the front of it. Also I use a principled bsdf thing (I didnt change the RGB Curve yet)

Comment: so in your screenshot it looks like you've tried the RGB Curve, does it improve? Also you have the Color > Bright/Contrast, you can lower down the Bright value...

Comment: it does, but now looks like this https://imgur.com/a/VLkvUO3, there is still a big amount of non-realism in it? any idea on how to fix this

Comment: maybe desaturate a bit (Color > Hue/Saturation node), also put a shadow (if it's here it's not very visible)

Comment: it is looking better now, how would you do the shadow? just puting a light there doesnt work that well

Comment: is it just for a single image? or animation? you could just paint on the wooden pier